# Using web3js get coin price on uniswap and sushiswap exchange without using their api

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js, erc20

I want to get token prices for uniswap and sushiswap exchange by using web.js

I am new to the crypto dev world, so please elaborate as much you can and if possible an example will be a lifesaver.
This is the best shot I could make... but don't know how to get `V3_pool_ABI` value

```
const JSBI = require('jsbi');
const Web3 = require('web3');

(async () => {
  const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/d5658a9beace4cd98d2c1216cf66b56a'));
  
  var factoryV3 = new web3.eth.Contract(
    [{"inputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint24","name":"fee","type":"uint24"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"int24","name":"tickSpacing","type":"int24"}],"name":"FeeAmountEnabled","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"oldOwner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnerChanged","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"token0","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"token1","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint24","name":"fee","type":"uint24"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"int24","name":"tickSpacing","type":"int24"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"pool","type":"address"}],"name":"PoolCreated","type":"event"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenA","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenB","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint24","name":"fee","type":"uint24"}],"name":"createPool","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"pool","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint24","name":"fee","type":"uint24"},{"internalType":"int24","name":"tickSpacing","type":"int24"}],"name":"enableFeeAmount","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint24","name":"","type":"uint24"}],"name":"feeAmountTickSpacing","outputs":[{"internalType":"int24","name":"","type":"int24"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint24","name":"","type":"uint24"}],"name":"getPool","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"parameters","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"factory","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"token0","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"token1","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint24","name":"fee","type":"uint24"},{"internalType":"int24","name":"tickSpacing","type":"int24"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"setOwner","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}], 
    '0x1F98431c8aD98523631AE4a59f267346ea31F984'
  );
  var pool_address = await factoryV3.methods.getPool('0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f', '0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2', 3000).call();
  var pool_1 = new web3.eth.Contract(V3_pool_ABI, pool_address);
  var pool_balance = await pool_1.methods.slot0.call().call();
  var sqrtPriceX96 = pool_balance[0];
  var number_1 =JSBI.BigInt(sqrtPriceX96 *sqrtPriceX96* (1e18)/(1e18)/JSBI.BigInt(2) ** (JSBI.BigInt(192)));
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer would be using oracle contracts, many defi apps depend on there price also.

How you would get it in solidity: ([link to blog](https://docs.chain.link/docs/get-the-latest-price/))

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract PriceConsumerV3 {

    AggregatorV3Interface internal priceFeed;

    /**
     * Network: Kovan
     * Aggregator: ETH/USD
     * Address: 0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331
     */
    constructor() {
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the latest price
     */
    function getLatestPrice() public view returns (int) {
        (
            uint80 roundID, 
            int price,
            uint startedAt,
            uint timeStamp,
            uint80 answeredInRound
        ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        return price;
    }
}
```

This can be replicated in js using the web3 library, just get this contract and use its functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Each pool is created from a factory contract, and they all use the same ABI.

You can lookup any of the valid pool addresses, for example the code from your question results in  [0xC2e9F25Be6257c210d7Adf0D4Cd6E3E881ba25f8](https://etherscan.io/address/0xC2e9F25Be6257c210d7Adf0D4Cd6E3E881ba25f8#code), and its ABI is already published.

```
var V3_pool_ABI = [{"inputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"int24","name":"tickLower","type":"int24"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"int24","name":"tickUpper","type":"int24"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount","type":"uint128"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount0","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount1","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Burn","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"int24","name":"tickLower","type":"int24"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"int24","name":"tickUpper","type":"int24"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount0","type":"uint128"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount1","type":"uint128"}],"name":"Collect","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount0","type":"uint128"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount1","type":"uint128"}],"name":"CollectProtocol","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount0","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount1","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"paid0","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"paid1","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Flash","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint16","name":"observationCardinalityNextOld","type":"uint16"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint16","name":"observationCardinalityNextNew","type":"uint16"}],"name":"IncreaseObservationCardinalityNext","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint160","name":"sqrtPriceX96","type":"uint160"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"int24","name":"tick","type":"int24"}],"name":"Initialize","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"int24","name":"tickLower","type":"int24"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"int24","name":"tickUpper","type":"int24"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount","type":"uint128"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount0","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount1","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Mint","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint8","name":"feeProtocol0Old","type":"uint8"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint8","name":"feeProtocol1Old","type":"uint8"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint8","name":"feeProtocol0New","type":"uint8"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint8","name":"feeProtocol1New","type":"uint8"}],"name":"SetFeeProtocol","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"int256","name":"amount0","type":"int256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"int256","name":"amount1","type":"int256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint160","name":"sqrtPriceX96","type":"uint160"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint128","name":"liquidity","type":"uint128"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"int24","name":"tick","type":"int24"}],"name":"Swap","type":"event"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"int24","name":"tickLower","type":"int24"},{"internalType":"int24","name":"tickUpper","type":"int24"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount","type":"uint128"}],"name":"burn","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount0","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount1","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"int24","name":"tickLower","type":"int24"},{"internalType":"int24","name":"tickUpper","type":"int24"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount0Requested","type":"uint128"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount1Requested","type":"uint128"}],"name":"collect","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount0","type":"uint128"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount1","type":"uint128"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount0Requested","type":"uint128"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount1Requested","type":"uint128"}],"name":"collectProtocol","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount0","type":"uint128"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount1","type":"uint128"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"factory","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"fee","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint24","name":"","type":"uint24"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"feeGrowthGlobal0X128","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"feeGrowthGlobal1X128","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount0","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount1","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"flash","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint16","name":"observationCardinalityNext","type":"uint16"}],"name":"increaseObservationCardinalityNext","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint160","name":"sqrtPriceX96","type":"uint160"}],"name":"initialize","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"liquidity","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint128","name":"","type":"uint128"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"maxLiquidityPerTick","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint128","name":"","type":"uint128"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"int24","name":"tickLower","type":"int24"},{"internalType":"int24","name":"tickUpper","type":"int24"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"amount","type":"uint128"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"mint","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount0","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount1","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"observations","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint32","name":"blockTimestamp","type":"uint32"},{"internalType":"int56","name":"tickCumulative","type":"int56"},{"internalType":"uint160","name":"secondsPerLiquidityCumulativeX128","type":"uint160"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"initialized","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint32[]","name":"secondsAgos","type":"uint32[]"}],"name":"observe","outputs":[{"internalType":"int56[]","name":"tickCumulatives","type":"int56[]"},{"internalType":"uint160[]","name":"secondsPerLiquidityCumulativeX128s","type":"uint160[]"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"positions","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint128","name":"liquidity","type":"uint128"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"feeGrowthInside0LastX128","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"feeGrowthInside1LastX128","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"tokensOwed0","type":"uint128"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"tokensOwed1","type":"uint128"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"protocolFees","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint128","name":"token0","type":"uint128"},{"internalType":"uint128","name":"token1","type":"uint128"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint8","name":"feeProtocol0","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"feeProtocol1","type":"uint8"}],"name":"setFeeProtocol","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"slot0","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint160","name":"sqrtPriceX96","type":"uint160"},{"internalType":"int24","name":"tick","type":"int24"},{"internalType":"uint16","name":"observationIndex","type":"uint16"},{"internalType":"uint16","name":"observationCardinality","type":"uint16"},{"internalType":"uint16","name":"observationCardinalityNext","type":"uint16"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"feeProtocol","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"unlocked","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"int24","name":"tickLower","type":"int24"},{"internalType":"int24","name":"tickUpper","type":"int24"}],"name":"snapshotCumulativesInside","outputs":[{"internalType":"int56","name":"tickCumulativeInside","type":"int56"},{"internalType":"uint160","name":"secondsPerLiquidityInsideX128","type":"uint160"},{"internalType":"uint32","name":"secondsInside","type":"uint32"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"zeroForOne","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"int256","name":"amountSpecified","type":"int256"},{"internalType":"uint160","name":"sqrtPriceLimitX96","type":"uint160"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"swap","outputs":[{"internalType":"int256","name":"amount0","type":"int256"},{"internalType":"int256","name":"amount1","type":"int256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"int16","name":"","type":"int16"}],"name":"tickBitmap","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"tickSpacing","outputs":[{"internalType":"int24","name":"","type":"int24"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"int24","name":"","type":"int24"}],"name":"ticks","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint128","name":"liquidityGross","type":"uint128"},{"internalType":"int128","name":"liquidityNet","type":"int128"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"feeGrowthOutside0X128","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"feeGrowthOutside1X128","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"int56","name":"tickCumulativeOutside","type":"int56"},{"internalType":"uint160","name":"secondsPerLiquidityOutsideX128","type":"uint160"},{"internalType":"uint32","name":"secondsOutside","type":"uint32"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"initialized","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"token0","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"token1","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}];
```

Comment: Petr Hejda do you know, how can I get the value for uniswap and sushiswap separately

Comment: @xyzxyz Your current code is using a hardcoded Uniswap factory address. You'll need to run it with a Sushiswap factory, that will generate a different pair contract address. Then you just copy-paste the ABI from the pair contract published data.

Comment: Petr Hejda Hey I am new to this, can you help me with an example of any single coin price on uniswap and sushiswap. This would really help me in learning all this... This means a lot thank you!!